# Tweeting from within meteor application

Tags: api, twitter, meteor

I am trying to build an app with Meteor that involves the user signing in with twitter, facebook, or google+, and then posting to those accounts from within the application.

First I'm trying to get twitter to work. I have my twitter sign in working, with the permission to tweet on their behalf working, but how to I actually send a tweet?

I think I need this: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/update but I can't figure out how the authentication works with Meteor.

Are there any examples that can help me here? Or tutorials?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an API to help you a bit unless you want to do it manually using REST with `Meteor.http`. I'd recommend you get meteorite: https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite

Its installed like a node module via `npm install -g meteorite`

Meteorite is a wrapper for meteor that lets you use the community packages over at http://atmosphere.meteor.com

The twitter package you could use is `twitter-api` installed via `mrt add twitter-api` : https://github.com/Sewdn/meteor-twitter-api

Once added using the server api you can add a tweet via:

**Server JS**

```
var twitter = new Twitter();

Meteor.methods({
    postTweet: function (text) {
        if(Meteor.user())
          twitter.postTweet(text),
          return true;
    }
});
```

**Client JS**

```
//Use this in your click handler where you want to post a tweet:

Meteor.call("postTweet", "This is Twweeeeeetttt!", function(err,result) {
    if(!err) {
        alert("Tweet posted");
    }
});
```

The api takes care of the user's oauth tokens so you don't have to worry too much

Comment: Awesome! Are there similar things for facebook and google plus?

Comment: Not as cool as this though, but its not too difficult to make them just as. You can use a npm module such as `fbgraph` (facebook) and `Google-Plus-API`. You would have to fetch the token from `Meteor.user().services.facebook` / google for each corresponding API, setting the user token and then access their corresponding post methods just like twitter's postTweet

Comment: Great. Doesn't look like Google-Plus-API supports posting yet, but that's okay. Will Meteor.user()_.services.facebook contain all the necessary auth stuff for the user that called the meteor method?

Comment: Yup its for the user that calls the method, it contains their access token over at Meteor.user().services.facebook.accessToken, with the graph api set this as the token with .setAccessToken and it should be good to go

Comment: I used sewdn:twitter-api , with Meteor 1.0 , It's working with search only ...  https://github.com/Sewdn/meteor-twitter-api/issues/11 am